# How do you add a marker on google map after button click on dialogFragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I'm trying to create an app that allows users to post a marker on a map which is the picture they captured along with the title they set. however, running this on my android device does not show the marker after the user clicks post on the dialogFragment, it just shows the one marker on sydney. I'd appreciate any help in understanding why the markers do not appear, as well as what I can do to fix this bug. Thank You!

This is my onView Created for The DialogFragment as well as the activityforresult for the image capture, here mMap is the GoogleMap defined in the MapActivity

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            // convert byte array to Bitmap

            image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,
                    byteArray.length);

            postImg.setImageBitmap(image);

        }
    }
}


  @Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Button post = view.findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
    final EditText popUpName = view.findViewById(R.id.popUpName);
    String title = getArguments().getString("title", "Post Popup");
    final ChipGroup tags = view.findViewById(R.id.chipGroup);
    getDialog().setTitle(title);
    postImg = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    postImg.setClickable(true);
    popUpName.requestFocus();
    //popUpName.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    postImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent,
                    CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
    post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String popUpTitle = popUpName.getText().toString();
            tags.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new ChipGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(ChipGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    Chip chip = group.findViewById(checkedId);
                    if (chip != null) {
                        String chipTagSelected = chip.getText().toString();
                    }

                    double maxX = 39.333977;
                    double minX = 39.326170;
                    double minY = -76.624140;
                    double maxY = -76.618813;

                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".######");
                    double diffX = maxX - minX;
                    double randomValueX = minX + Math.random() * diffX;

                    double diffY = maxY - minY;
                    double randomValueY = minY + Math.random() * diffY;

                    Marker marker = MapsView.mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(randomValueX, randomValueY))
                            .title(popUpTitle)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(image)));

                    marker.setTag(0);
                }
            });

            //
            //popUpName.getText().toString()
            dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

Here is my xml file for DialogFragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="124dp"
    android:text="Add PopUp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/popUpName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/popUpName"
    android:layout_width="296dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:hint="Popup Name"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDone"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:text="Post"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/lightBlue"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chipGroup" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="127dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="112dp"
    android:text="Tags"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/popUpName" />

<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:chipSpacing="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:singleSelection="true"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/Dog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dog"
        app:chipEndPadding="12dp"
        app:chipStartPadding="12dp"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/bg_chip_state_list"/>

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/Squirrels"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Squirrels"
        app:chipEndPadding="12dp"
        app:chipStartPadding="12dp"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/bg_chip_state_list"/>

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/Bird"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bird"
        app:chipEndPadding="12dp"
        app:chipStartPadding="12dp"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/bg_chip_state_list"/>

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/People"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="People"
        app:chipEndPadding="8dp"
        app:chipStartPadding="8dp"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/bg_chip_state_list"/>

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/Random"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Random"
        app:chipEndPadding="8dp"
        app:chipStartPadding="8dp"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/bg_chip_state_list"/>

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/Animals"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Animals"
        app:chipEndPadding="8dp"
        app:chipStartPadding="8dp"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/bg_chip_state_list"/>
</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="134dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

here is my onCreate for the MapActivity, onMapReady is just the basic implementation for a MapACtivity with the marker set on sydney

```
public class MapsView extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

public static GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_view);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.add_post);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Snackbar.make(view, "Here's a Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                   // .setAction("Action", null).show();
            showPostDialog();
        }
    });
}

private void showPostDialog() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    PostActivity postFragmentDialog = PostActivity.newInstance("Some title");
    postFragmentDialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit");

    //inal EditText popUpName = findViewById(R.id.popUpName);

}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code onClick from dilaog , and it will add the marker on google map. Berfore that just check if mapReady() is sucessfully called or not.

```
   mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng destination) {

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        options.position(destination);
        options.title("Lat=" + destination.latitude + ", Long=" + destination.longitude);
        Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(options);
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));
    }
});
```

Comment: is mGoogleMap by previously defined mMap? I added these changes, but unfortunately the marker still does not appear on the map after clicking post. I am also confused as to why the onMapClick occurs inside the dialogue if the dialogue does not contain the map.